# Ideas on dynamic python logging

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, dynamic

I have an app which runs several instances of main app depending on external parameters. The main app imports few libraries which in turn import other libraries. They all have a global

`LOGGER = logging.getLogger('module_name')`

The logger is configured as file handler so all the logs get written to an external file (all logs written to same file). Now I want to write log to different files based on a certain name that is passed to the main app. I need some thing like

`LOGGER = logging.getLogger(dynamic_criteria_name)`

The result will be multiple log files dynamic_criteria_name.log, dynamic_criteria_name.log, etc created and any time logger is called from any of the module it should write to the correct file based on the criteria it was called under.

But the problem is the LOGGER is global. I can pass the logger or the `dynamic_criteria_name` to each function to write to log but it sounds wrong some how. May be I'm just paranoid! I have modules which have sometimes only functions in them. I don't want to pass the logger all around I guess.

I thought about AOP for a while but I don't think it is really cross cutting as it is dynamically generated the logger looks to me as cross cutting but within one instance of the main app. I have thought about other ways to hack global states but I think the dynamic nature makes it all not possible at least in my head.

Below is the pseudocode (I haven't tried it running it) but it explains better what I'm talking about I think. As you can see module_1 imports module_2 and module_3, they both have a global LOGGER, and module_3 calls module_4. I'd like to find out if I can write to the separate log file from module_2 or module_3 without passing name explicitly to each imported module function. I can add multiple handler to logger with different file name but how can I refer to the correct logger from another module given they are all global at the moment.

```
# module_1.py
import logging
import time

import module_2
import module_3

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()


def start_main_loop(name):
    while True:
        module_2.say_boo()
        module_3.say_foo()
        LOGGER.debug('Sleeping...')
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    for i in xrange(10):
        start_main_loop(i)

#----------------------------------------------------        
# module_2.py

import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()

def say_boo():
    msg = 'boo'
    LOGGER.debug(msg)
    LOGGER.debug(say_twice(msg))

def say_twice(msg):
    LOGGER.debug('Called say twice')
    return msg * 2

#----------------------------------------------------    
# module_3.py

import logging

import module_4

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()

def say_foo():
    msg = 'foo'
    LOGGER.debug(msg)
    LOGGER.debug(say_twice(msg))
    module_4.say_bar()

def say_twice(msg):
    LOGGER.debug('Called say twice')
    return msg * 2

#----------------------------------------------------    
# module_4.py

import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()

def say_bar():
    msg = 'bar'
    LOGGER.debug(msg)
```

I'm willing to explore any ideas people might have. Hope I have explained myself clearly if not please let me know, I can rephrase the question. Thanks!

Comment: Each module can use it's `__name__` as the logger name. If you want to add the function name to the logger name, each function has the `func_name` property.

Comment: Sorry - I need different log files based on the dynamic name.

Comment: You can have any number of handlers in a logger, that should not be a problem.

Comment: Not sure if handlers are my problem. I want to know how I can pass the logger reference or the criteria to other modules without having to explicitly pass them to function calls as a parameter.

Comment: You need to describe what messages you want to go into what files. Also your example looks to have a mistake - the `logging.getLogger('Sleeping...')` looks wrong.

Comment: Sorry corrected that. This is where the code stands at the moment roughly. If there are multiple handlers which write to different files, I still need a way to pass the "name" to each `logging.getLogger` in different modules. I'm not sure how to address that without explicitly passing the "name" to each imported module function and moving global logger to inside each function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass loggers around: loggers are singletons. If code in multiple modules makes calls to `getLogger('foo')`, the same instance is returned for each call. So there is no need to pass logger instances around. In general the logger name indicates where a logging call originates from, so the `__name__` value makes most sense. You could have code in a module `foo` log to a logger named `bar` - nothing prevents you doing this - it just hasn't been found especially useful in practice.

Sounds like AOP is overkill. Rather than passing logger names around, you might consider adding multiple handlers to the root logger, with specific filters on each handler to ensure that specific things go in specific files, according to your particular requirements.

Comment: I've updated my question with an example. It would be great if you could explain your idea with some code. I know I can add multiple handlers(I've used RotatingFileHandler) to logger but I haven't used filters before. The part I'm struggling to get is how can I have multiple instances of global LOGGER based on given context like 'name' in my example. Thanks!